# How do I dynamically update rows in the new MySQL table with dynamic data populating the rows in the old table?

Tags: mysql, dynamic, rows, transfer

I have the following SQL code that works fine for transferring rows of data from the old table to the new table. (working in MySQL workbench)

```
INSERT INTO us_compensation.RPBAR 
(ORG_SEC_ID ,
FYE, 
TOTAL_SALARY_PAID , 
OTHER_COMP_PAID ,
TOTAL_BONUS_PAID , 
PERFORMANCE_EQUITY_TIME_VESTING_OPTIONS_TIME_VESTING_STOCK,
TOTAL) 
SELECT DISTINCT
    ORG_SEC_ID,
    FYE,
    TOTAL_SALARY_PAID,
    OTHER_COMP_PAID,
    TOTAL_BONUS_PAID,
    PERFORMANCE_EQUITY + TIME_VESTING_OPTIONS + TIME_VESTING_STOCK,
    TOTAL_SALARY_PAID + OTHER_COMP_PAID + TOTAL_BONUS_PAID
      + PERFORMANCE_EQUITY + TIME_VESTING_OPTIONS + TIME_VESTING_STOCK
FROM
    equilar.realizablepay
group by ORG_SEC_ID
HAVING MAX(FYE);
```

What I need help with is the following. The rows in the old table change automatically as new data comes in. However, the rows in the new table (RPBAR) do not reflect the new data. What happens is that the new table has all the rows with the old data from the old table and appends at the bottom of the new table the new data that comes into the old table.

I want the new table not to store the old data in the rows but update the concerned rows with the new data from the old table (where all the concerned rows are updated with the new data).

How can I make the new table reflect the new data in the old table's rows and not have the new table both the old data and the new data?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html) on your new table.  In that trigger you can execute multiple statements to conditionally update your old table.

Comment: I am working with the suggestion by eggyall for creating a view. I am not familiar with triggers (newbie with SQL) but reading about it now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you simply want a [`VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/views.html)?

```
CREATE VIEW us_compensation.RPBAR AS
  SELECT DISTINCT
           ORG_SEC_ID,
           FYE,
           TOTAL_SALARY_PAID,
           OTHER_COMP_PAID,
           TOTAL_BONUS_PAID,
           PERFORMANCE_EQUITY + TIME_VESTING_OPTIONS + TIME_VESTING_STOCK
             AS PERFORMANCE_EQUITY_TIME_VESTING_OPTIONS_TIME_VESTING_STOCK,
           TOTAL_SALARY_PAID + OTHER_COMP_PAID + TOTAL_BONUS_PAID
             + PERFORMANCE_EQUITY + TIME_VESTING_OPTIONS + TIME_VESTING_STOCK
             AS TOTAL
  FROM     equilar.realizablepay
  GROUP BY ORG_SEC_ID
  HAVING   MAX(FYE)
;
```

Comment: Thanks. But since the table RPBAR already exists (as the 2nd table) how do I include the view statement without trying to create RPBAR?

Comment: @user1542006: Drop the table first.

Comment: Ok. What I did was renamed RPBAR as RPBAR1 and the execution was successful, but 0 rows affected. I have around 4000 rows. Further, the resulting view was not displayed.

Comment: @user1542006: You have created a view (which is a sort of virtual table); now `SELECT * FROM us_compensation.RPBAR` just as you would from a normal table.

Comment: My mistake-the query works perfectly. One question though. How does a 'VIEW' differ from a 'TABLE'? And I will need to use the data in the VIEW-pull out all the data using a Python program and use the data for some other function. Will the VIEW allow me to do that?

Comment: @user1542006: You query a view just like you do a table, but it executes the underlying query on each invocation so always contains the latest *view* of your data.

Comment: Thanks eggyal. Then I'll stick with the view unless their reqmt. is a table - no questions asked.